# Overriding Proxy in Device Settings for NSURLSessionConfiguration?

Tags: ios, proxy, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Is it possible to ignore the proxy settings that are in the device network settings, and instead use no proxy when using an NSURLSession ?

Basically I want to fall back on using no proxy if the connection fails.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that providing an empty *connectionProxyDictionary* in a session configuration should do the trick.  Note that it must be an actual empty dictionary.  Setting it to nil uses the default system proxy settings.

Comment: I wonder why this worked

Comment: Because there had to be a way to distinguish between "use the default settings" and "use no settings", and treating a NULL/nil value as "use defaults" is cheaper than providing a separate boolean property somewhere, I'd imagine.  :-)